# Made successive wix lightbox modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, velo

I try to made a **terms and condition** modal next to my register form on my wix website.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSvnL.png)

I have two custom dialogs #lightbox1 & #lightbox2. After user clicks REGISTER NOW (#button2) on #lightbox1 another custom popup dialog (#lightbox2) with some text and OK button should be shown. After user clicks ACCEPTER on this popup, the register should be confirmed.

That is the code i added :

```
$w.onReady(() => {
  $w('#button2').on('click', function () {
   $w("#lightbox2").show();
   });
});
```

The problem is not recognize #lightbox2 and it throws me error :

"*An element with the ID '#lightbox2' does not exist on this page. Select another element and view or edit its ID in the Properties & Events panel.*"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYgPj.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAnVd.jpg)

Then, if a charitable soul wants to help me, I'll welcome him with open arms .

Answer (score 1):

Wix only allows one lightbox at a time to function, as an alternative approach you can add Wix Multi-State component inside the lightbox popup and switch the views with the help of code

[Wix Velo Tutorial for Multi-State Boxes](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-tutorial-working-with-multi-state-boxes-and-code)